# Live chat using AJAX

Tags: ajax, chat, ape

Hello everyone 
I just wanted to know if I use AJAX for my chat engine, will it crash my server or it will work fine for a traffic of about 1500 people at a time ??

Also suggest me some way to make automatic ajax request to update the contents of chat box. How much delay between consecutive query should be set so that it doesn't cause my server to overload ???

Thanks in advance :) :)

Comment: So you mean, using AJAX is fine.. even if I call a request every 5 sec for every chat ???

Comment: Hope u would like to answer now :P

Comment: even though I'd love to answer your question, it's simply not possible. Sorry. It depends on __so many__ factors (e.g. server, language, user activity, latency, etc) that even the best answer would  be a wild guess. I can make a wild guess if you really, really want to. It's not going to be useful though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your requirements, you might want to look into WebSockets. At a local hacknight, we produced a simple chat system pretty quickly using http://faye.jcoglan.com/. It's a pub sub service that you can use javascript on the client side to subscribe to a specific channel. Then it's just a matter of coding the front end to work with the input and output.